# How to have TypeScript generic function with type argument being keyof an object have return type of that object's key's value

Tags: typescript, generics, strong-typing, typescript4.0

I have a several object types:

```
type Slave = {
  myKey:string
}

type AnotherSlave = {
  anotherKey:string
}
```

And a master type that contains some keys, and these object types as those keys' values as below:

```
type Master = {
  key1: Slave
  key2: AnotherSlave
}
```

I have a generic function:

```
myFunc<T = keyof Master>(key:T){
  const someObj = {} // external call that returns "any" type
  return someObj; // I want to cast it to some strongly type here.
}
```

The someObj is guaranteed to have the type from `Master[T]`'s value, in other words:

If the key is `key1`, `someObj` is the type of `Slave`. If the key is `key2`, `someObj` is the type of `AnotherSlave`. I've wrote the types depending on what's coming from the external call of someObj anyway so it's guaranteed to have that type.

I naively tried `return someObj as Master[T]` but it errs `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Master'`.

How can I make the function return strongly typed key's value type? I'm on TypeScript 4.6.3.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. There are a lot of errors an invalid syntax

Comment: The relevant part of the question is pretty much clear. Obviously, these `[...]`s and `someKeys...` are not actual code, just irrelevant.

Comment: I agree, however people usually don't want to waste their time providing dummy data to others people question. If you don't want to do it and you are interested in getting an answer, why person who will dedicate their time answering your question should do it ? I don't want to be rude or "toxic person from StackOverflow", but usually people are providing code samples with invalid syntax

Comment: I will upvote your question, to increase visibility and to make sure that you don't have negative experience.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I agree. Actually I had a fully populated code with real data on my project but because of NDA I had to replicate it from scratch here. Edited and fixed invalid syntax issues now.

Comment: If you are interested in strong type validation of server response, I recommend you to use [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) or just using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a return value and use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on the returned `someObj`

```js
function myFunc<T extends keyof Master>(key:T): Master[T] {
  const someObj = {}
  return someObj as Master[T];
}

const test = myFunc("key1") // <-- type is Slave
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygNgQwG7QLxQN4CgpQLYgDSEIAXAM7ABOAlgHYDmWAvllqJFAIJ0D2wACwhV4yNJhxQEfQcOJlKtRizYdoAWQSVhUdNlwBrEgEZSsRCklGQAJjM9+QkRYgqsAMwCudAMbAavHT4IABi3j4APAAqUBAAHsAQdAAm5FDWvO5QmtpUAHwAFNakUQCUZjmJVADaUQC6Erg+gZRQ5Lx4EADyAEYAVrqYrLhUEMCeVEHtnb0DWtlaVbV1ANxuzXSt1saDBGG+BQBE24elUAD051ARALQ3UGpQNGmilhtbJDa7oeFH1janC5XW73R7PbgyJyvCBAA)